# javax.mail.MessagingException: A4 NO COPY failed or partially completed

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I am trying to move outlook emails into another folder after parsing them so that the same emails are not parsed again in Java. the code works fine sometimes but other times it throws an Exception after partially executing. I am not sure what is causing it.

Exception:

```
Dec 07, 2015 4:55:50 PM email.TransferReadEmails removeReadEmails
SEVERE: ERROR!!A4 NO COPY failed or partially completed.
javax.mail.MessagingException: A4 NO COPY failed or partially completed.;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A4 NO COPY failed or partially completed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.copyMessages(IMAPFolder.java:1553)
    at email.TransferReadEmails.transfer(TransferReadEmails.java:32)
    at email.TransferReadEmails.removeReadEmails(TransferReadEmails.java:65)
    at email.ReadingEmail.readEmails(ReadingEmail.java:146)
    at swingFrames.LaunchPanel.runProcess(LaunchPanel.java:994)
    at swingFrames.LaunchPanel.startOperationButtonMouseClicked(LaunchPanel.java:850)
    at swingFrames.LaunchPanel.access$600(LaunchPanel.java:48)
    at swingFrames.LaunchPanel$7.mouseClicked(LaunchPanel.java:191)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A4 NO COPY failed or partially completed.
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:344)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:366)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.copy(IMAPProtocol.java:1479)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.copy(IMAPProtocol.java:1461)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.copyMessages(IMAPFolder.java:1545)
    ... 39 more
```

My Code:

```
//Function to copy and delete the messages from INBOX (Destination Folder: READ)
private static void transfer(Folder folder_source, Folder folder_dest, Message[] messages)
        throws Exception {       

    //If the READ folder does not exists create that folder
    if (!folder_dest.exists()) {
        folder_dest.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
    } 

    //Copy read messages from INBOX to READ folder
    folder_source.copyMessages(messages, folder_dest);

    //Delete the read messages from INBOX
    Flags deleted = new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED);
    folder_source.setFlags(messages, deleted, true);
    folder_source.expunge(); // or folder.close(true);


    System.out.println("Successfully");

    //Close the INBOX folder
    folder_source.close(false);
}
```

Comment: No idea why it's failing, that's a question for Microsoft.  Perhaps the server logs contain some clue?  When it fails, you could try copying the messages one at a time to find out if it's a particular message that's causing the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me how to see Microsoft server logs? I figured out if the number of emails exceed roughly 250 at a time I get that error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I assume you use some Windows or Exchange log file viewer.